# Data validation using old field value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, validation

I'm developing an application on CakePHP, but i'm a newbie with data validation.
What i need is check a datetime value when the field will be modified, so i need to check old datetime value and verify the new is equal or higher. 
I think the best is use custom validation, but don't know how to get the old value of the field, and how to distinguish from creation to edit.

A simple example here:

1) I register a new Event in my db, it have Name, Start date, End date, ecc...

2) I want to edit this Event, so i insert a new Start and a new End date, Now i need this validation:

if old end value is before new one:

update record;

else:

data validation fails, don't update the record;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data validation goes in your Model (it can be done in your controller if you really want but Cake makes things easier if it's done in the Model).

In your "Event" Model:

```
$public validate = array(    //each field can have its own validation rule set here
    'end_date' => array(
        'rule' => 'customEndDateValidation',    //the name of our custom validation function to use
        'on' => 'update',    //only do this when we update a record
        'message' => 'New end date must be greater than previous end date'    //message if validation fails
    )
);

public function customEndDateValidation($check) {
    //get previous end date
    $old_record = $this->find(
        'all',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Event.id' => $this->data[$this->alias]['id']
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Event.end_date'
            )
        )
    );

    //if the new end date is greater than the old one return true - otherwise it will reach the return false
    if (strtotime($check['end_date']) > strtotime($old_record['Event']['end_date'])) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

For more on validation in Cake have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

Answer (score 0):

just add 2 attributs of your table : "created" and "modified"

It 's a standard of CakePHP

[if isn't the answer that you search](http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Compare-2-dates-in-cakePHP-td2257244.html)

---

//MY TABLE

```
Project
[0]--Id
[1]--Name
[2]--DateEdit
[3]--OlderDateEdit
[4]--modified
[5]--created
```

//http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#adding-your-own-validation-methods

//View

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('Project.DateEdit',array("label"=>"Date edit"));
echo $this->Form->hidden('Project.OlderDateEdit');
```

//CONTROLLER

```
<?php
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (empty($this->data)) {
            $this->Project->id = $id;
            $this->data = $this->Project->read();

            $this->data['Project']['OlderDateEdit']=$this->data['Project']['DateEdit'];
        } 
        else {

            if ($this->Project->save($this->data['Project'])) {

            }
        }
    }
```

//MODEL

```
<?php
class Project extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'verif_date' => array(
            'rule'    => array('comparison-Dte','OlderDateEdit'),
            'message' => 'ur datetime is older'
        )
    );
```

//AppModel//

```
<?php
public function comparison-Dte($check, $limit) {

        $valeur = array_values($check);
        $valeur = $valeur[0];
        $OldDateEdit = $limit;
        ));
        return $NewDateEdit > $OldDateEdit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it isn't about datetime for created and modified, i have to record events in a table, so i have an Start and an End column, for some development logics, is not possible to modify the end date to and early date than before. What i need is a check of the value, but in model validation rules, to avoid wrong editing.

Comment: Can you test with comparison. I don't know if it s work on date =) . If isn't work compare ur two date in the controller before the save.

Comment: Test with comparison? Please can you explain what you mean? it's the think i'm searching for... i want to avoid check on controller, because there are various actions who could edit the data, and best solution is to put to a lower level (model)

Comment: i edited my answer under the "hr", the validate is in the model

Comment: compare didn't use a different field? ah ok... it's a lil workaround, so i have to mask real field and update a different one... but in that case you don't override the edit field, and in the last, validation doesn't work if you use the real field...

Comment: Maybe i don't understand your problem :/ | you mask your old date to compare with the new date. if this date is old, ur data aren't save else your data are save and u have save ur new date on "edit" and ur old date in "test-edit"

Comment: You insert a date and register the event, maybe in future you want to modify it, when you edit your record, can change the date: what I want to check this datetime value (the one insert in editing form) among the old value, registered on the database, and update the record only if the new value is bigger than the old.

Comment: i edited my answer. i add the table structure (with the older date attribut).Maybe u can use $var without save this in the slq but i'm not sure. We create a specific function for the validate. $date1 < $date2 work with php 5.2 nd +